# append <div> tag inside dynamically created <li> using PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is for a WordPress site I am working with for practice.

i am using `Feedzy rss plugin` to dynamically create rss feed items on different pages.

so..if the html structure was already there i could have just added it in the `.php` file directly  inside.

But it is created when the site loads.

That is why i need a php function to find the `<li>` with `class="item"` and append the

```
<div class="mainbox" id="mainbox">
    <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
    <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
    <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
    <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
</div>
```

The rss plugin creates this html structure -

```
   <ul>
     <li class="item">               
        <div class="image" ></div>
        <span class="title"></span>
        <div class="content" ></div>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

And I need to create it like this:

```
<li class="item">               
    <div class="image" ></div>
    <span class="title"></span>
    <div class="content" ></div>
    <div class="mainbox" id="mainbox">
        <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
        <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
        <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
        <img src="" alt="" class="imgbox">
    </div>
</li>
```

Please help fix the issue.

This is what i tried and it didnt do anythhing.

```
function wrap_anchor_text_with_span( $content ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && preg_match( '~class=\"(.*?)\"~', $content ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace_callback( '~class=\"(.*?)\"~', '_add_span', $content );
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrap_anchor_text_with_span', 10);

function _add_span( $matches ) {
    // $matches[1] will contain class and other properties of the wrapper tag. Using a preg_match - assign $class to be the css class from the parent function.
    preg_match('~class=\"(.*?)\"~', $matches[1], $class);

    if ( $class[1] !== 'item' )  { // If the class from wrap_anchor_text function isn't item. Return the original content
        // return the original content
        return $matches[0];
    } else {
        // do what you want here.
        return '<li class="' . $class[1] . '"><div class="mainbox"></div></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tagged PHP ? if you don't have any PHP code in your question. What did you try ? You need to add more details. **Please help fix the issue.** which issue ?

Comment: You might be better off asking the plugin creator (or their support forum if there is one) how you can change the output HTML.

Comment: @executable i don't if i should upload whole theme php code here but i have created the site this much and added custom page column changer and color and bg color changer. and yes i created the top custom menu and even tried adding symbols to it. which didnt look good so i deleted that part.
i am not a php developer or a developer. i am a beginner to wordpress and can understand basic fundamentals of programming but for now its been 5 days..around 20 hours of finding answers and asking a lot of people. this is the example of how it is now.
https://ibb.co/gw6c81C

Comment: Show the PHP part

Comment: @executable i updated the question with the php part. i just need this code to create a block for social sharing widget within each feed item. something like this. https://mllj2j8xvfl0.i.optimole.com/w:auto/h:auto/q:98/https://s15165.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Jetpack-Social-Buttons.png

Comment: @executable so......? i updated the PHP part you asked for.